# Is there a better way to get/store information about a item than my current method?

Tags: c#

If I have created a new enum for example:

```
enum itemName{
    shortsword, ironChestplate, leatherCap}
```

And for each of those items I had fixed information about each item, what would be the best way to store and retrieve the data?
Currently I use a series of conversion methods that use switch statements to return the correct information, for example:

```
itemType convertItemNameToItemType(itemName itemName){
    switch(itemName){
        case itemName.shortsword:
            return itemType.handEquipment;
        case itemName.ironChestplate:
            return itemType.bodyEquipment;
        case itemName.leatherCap:
            return itemType.headEquipment;
        }
      }

int convertItemNameToItemCost(itemName itemName){
    switch(itemName){
        case itemName.shortsword:
            return 3;
        case itemName.ironChestplate:
            return 8;
        case itemName.leatherCap:
            return 2;
        }
      }
```

These are just examples but there are more conversion methods to return more information about the said item, as well as many more items.
This means that there is a lot of bulky code with the amount of switch statements.

Is there a better way to store and retrieve this information? This information will not be changed throughout the running of the program.

Thanks.

Edit:
By better I mean a more efficient and less bulky way to gather the information about a enum, rather than just using a switch statement. The data I may want to get is (more columns are needed but this is just a example):

| itemName | itemType | itemCost | itemTrainingRequirement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shortsword | handEquipment | 3 | martial |
| ironChestplate | bodyEquipment | 8 | martial |
| leatherCap | headEquipment | 2 | none |

and currently I only have switch statements to convert from one to another when I need to.

Comment: Do you have a class comprised all of these enum values for each specific item? Or all they all just disjoint enums floating around?

Comment: Please define "better" in objective terms that can be judged by people other than you. Otherwise, the question is off topic.

Comment: The default item numbers start at zero and increment by one.  So youcan create arrays.  int[] convertItemNameToItemCost = {3,8,2};  Then retrieve convertItemNameToItemCost[(int)shortsword]

Comment: If I were you I would look into probably using a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0) for both of them. Also as a side note, I would recommend reading up on [C# Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) to make things a little easier to read for you and everyone else reading your code.

Comment: Also "better" is a very opinionated word. Please specify exactly in what way you need it to be better (i.e. performance, less lines, easier to add to, etc.).

Comment: I think you'd be a far better off defining your item as a class with properties such as `Cost` and `Type`, etc.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb they are all just enums at the moment that I will use for logic ie: if (itemName) is handEquipment, do X

Comment: @HereticMonkey, see edit

Comment: @Jesse Can a dictionary have more dimensions than just two? also see my edit

Comment: @WillMasters In that case maybe just create a class with properties for every piece of information you have, then create a bunch of instances of it with the appropriate information and put them into a list. If you don't want it all to be hardcoded, I would look into storing it in a JSON/YAML file, or potentially even a database depending on how much of it there is and how you want to add to/update it. You can then use LINQ to select the item you need. If you're worried about performance, it might be faster to make a couple dictionaries with keys being the info you would be most likely to have.

Comment: @Jesse Can you point me in the direction of a good tutorial for one of these storage methods? As I will likely have over to create 50 unique objects of this class. The information wont change while the program is running but will need to be accessed to create the objects

Comment: JSON and YAML are very similar as far as the required code is concerned. All you need is a library ([Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or [YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet#readme) respectively) to convert between objects and text. Then you simply serialize the objects and write them to the file to save, and read the file then deserialize the text to get your objects. Databases on the other hand are a whole different beast. MariaDB and PostgreSQL are fairly popular ones. You'll need to learn SQL to use these, but they are much *much* faster than reading files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum itemName{    shortsword, ironChestplate, leatherCap}

//-- assuming you want to keep this enum - create following class
class { itemName Name, itemType iType, decimal itemCost}
//-- now create dictionary 
Dictionary<itemName, item> items = new ... 
//-- add all items in dictionary by creating objects 
// then when you need it - just return 
return items[itemName.shortword] and so on
```

if you dont need enum, then itemName can be string and you could follow similar approach